# Apple in honey atoning for adams sin

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, symbols-symbology, honey

I've heard that the apple dipped in the honey is a segulah to atone for the sin of Adam. What is the source for, and a more detailed explanation of the apple dipped in the honey atoning for the sin of Adam harishon?

Comment: Who said it does?

Comment: It's hearsay.  I'm asking if anyone has heard of the concept

Comment: You should clarify that in your question. It's odd to just make an assertion and expect us to source it for you.

Comment: Obligatory "eitz hadaas was not an apple tree." But see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20355/6592

Comment: Yes. We should all know that by now. But the reminder is appreciated

Comment: Sounds like something bogus to me. As said above. NOT AN APPLE TREE! Thus, anyone who proposed it was Christian-influenced, grossly ignorant, or both.